# How to access session variable in other file

Tags: perl, session

```
# Object initialization:
use CGI::Session;

$session = CGI::Session->new();

$CGISESSID = $session->id();

# Send proper HTTP header with cookies:

print $session->header();

# Storing data in the session:

$session->param('User_id', 'U00002');
```

This script is written in some file say abc.pl.

Now I want access the User_id in some other perl file, say xyz.pl.
How to do that?
Do I need to make any change in this script?

Comment: You obviously have read the [synopsis from the documentation of `CGI::Session`](http://p3rl.org/CGI::Session#SYNOPSIS) because your code is derived from it. The very next item in the synopsis tells you how to retrieve a session.

Comment: yes.. but it is in same file. Actually i am trying to access the variable in other file, But unfortunately i am not able to get it.. can u pls give me snip code to achieve this.

Comment: I realise now that you have no idea how sessions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use CGI::Session qw();
my $s = CGI::Session->new;
$s->param(User_id => 'U00002');
my $id = $s->id; # e.g. '4cd29ac608405e4d0a463d153e64defd'
```

Pass the id to where it's needed.

```
use CGI::Session qw();
my $s = CGI::Session->new($id);
print $s->param('User_id'); # 'U00002'
```