# Can't invoke submit queries in PERL CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

Hey so I am trying to make a simple 'dating website' however I'm struggling with CGI aspect :( Mainly I'm having trouble with forms(I think I'm not too sure what I'm struggling with).

I have this statement

```
print header, start_html("EngCupid"), h2("EngCupid"), start_form;

if (!param() || param("home")) {
    show_welcome();
} elsif (param("browse")) {
    browse_page();
} elsif (param("search")) {
    search_users();
} elsif (param("username")) {
    search_results(); 
} else {
    print "fail";
}   
print end_form, end_html;
exit 0;
```

To Handle the general navigation of the website. However, I'm struggling when it comes to submit buttons etc inside these functions. So my browse_page() function is

```
sub browse_page {
        print h2("Browse Page");
    print p;
    if (param("next")) {
        $hidden_variable = param("x") + 1;
    }
    param('x', $hidden_variable);
    $hidden_variable = 0;
    print hidden('x');
    print submit("next", "Next");
    print submit("home", "Home"), " ", submit("search", "Search Users");

}
```

Which is supposed to increment a variable that I need to use for further functions every time I press the next key. However, whenever I press the next key it just prints fail as in the form isn't being passed?

Do I need a new form inside each function I am printing? I tried it but it still didn't work. Just a little lost in forms in general.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe the problem is that the `x` is not being sent back from client to server, maybe you wanted

```
print hidden('x', param('x'));
```

Also, why do you set `$hidden_variable` to 0? After submitting, the script will run again, the old value of the variable will not be accessible anymore.

Comment: Well I need to iterate through a folder 10 at a time (folder has a few hundred files) So i want to increment a use-able value every time I click next.

Comment: Also why is it when I press next it won't go into the if statement?

Comment: @JustinJuntang: Because `param('browse')` is no longer true.

Comment: OH! I get it :S But how do I make it so that browse is true then? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: @JustinJuntang: You can add a new hidden `browse` field. Or, you can create different scripts for home, browse, search etc. Or, you can use a session to keep information across loads.

Comment: Do you think you could provide some code example? I'm not to familiar with CGI syntax. Also I have a feeling that I won't be properly be able to increment my variable. How do I create a variable that is 'global' in the sense when I print a new page it won't get erased.

Comment: choroba, do not send people off to Google. Instead link to a useful/authoritative answer on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774538/how-to-access-session-variable-in-other-file